# In binary classfication, encoding target varible from yes=1, no=0 gives different results than yes=0, no=1 in XGboosting

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, precision-recall

I am new to Machine Learning. In a binary classfication problem, we encode/transform target variable like **yes=1** and **No=0** (directly in dataset) it gives follwoing results

- Accuracy:95
- Recall: 90
- Precision:94
- **F1: 92**

but if we encode/transform target variable inversely like **yes=0** and **No=1**(directly in dataset), then it gives these results

- Accuracy:95
- Recall:97
- Precision:94
- **F1:95**

I am using XGboost algorithm. All other variables are numeric(positive and negative)
Although accuracy is same in both cases but I assume that **F1 should also be same in both cases**. So why it is giving different results.
I know that scikit-learn can handle encoding but why F1 is different in both cases?

```
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split(X,encoded_Y,test_size=0.3,random_state=100,shuffle=True)
clf_xgb = xgb.XGBClassifier(nthread=1,random_state=100)
clf_xgb.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
xgb_pred = clf_xgb.predict(xtest)
xgb_pred_prb=clf_xgb.predict_proba(xtest)[:,1]
print(confusion_matrix(xgb_pred,ytest))
# [984   57]
# [103 1856]

#Find Accuracy of XGBoost
accuracy_xgb = accuracy_score(ytest,xgb_pred)
print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy_xgb)

#Find Recall of XGBoost
recall_xgb = recall_score(ytest,xgb_pred)
recall_xgb

#Find Precision of XGBoost
precision_xgb = precision_score(ytest,xgb_pred)
precision_xgb

#Find F1 Score XGB
xgb_f1=f1_score(ytest,xgb_pred)
xgb_f1
```

Comment: Did you get the same results everytime whenever you are running the code ? I meant the same precision every time with the same encoding ?

Comment: @coderina Yes, every time I run the code with same endcoding gives me same results for precision, f1, recall, accuracy.

Comment: @MuhammadIbrar: the reason for this behavior could be, that ML models usually use a random seed, which is fixed, so the results are repeatable. If you don't like that, you should set the seed to a random number every time you train your model and also for the `train_test_split` or folds.

Comment: For `XGBClassifier` this argument is named `random_state` I guess. Just try `random_state=random.randint(0, 2147483647)`. Just recognized, that you explicictely fix the `random_state` for `train_test_split` to 1, so it always will select the same records for train and test.

Comment: Btw. this is exactly the same for light-gbm. if you ommit the seed parameter there, all random seeds are initialized to a constant int everytime you run it, so if nothing changes in the data or the parameters, you will get exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the f1 score and precision and recall are connected.

The formulas are:

```
f1= 2/((recall^-1)+(precision^-1))
```

and

```
recall= true_positives / (true_positives + false_negatives)
precision= true_positives / (true_positives + false_positives)
```

So recall and precision are depending on what you define as positive (1). If you Switch your positive / negative cases, like you do by mapping yes/no differently, you get a totally different result.
You can see that by the following calculation, assuming you have 100 yes and 4900 nos and get the follwoing result:

```
              ----------
              |YES|NO  |
|-------------|---|----|
|predicted_YES| 90|   5|
|-------------|---|----|
|predicted_NO | 10|4895|
------------------------
```

Then in case you define `YES` as positive (1), you get

```
precision=90/(90+5)=0.947
recall=90/(90+10)=0.9
f1= 2/(precision^(-1) + recall^(-1))=0.923
```

While if you define `NO` as positive (1), you get:

```
precision=4895/(4895+10)=0.998
recall=4895/(4895+10)=0.999
f1= 2 / (precision^(-1) + recall^(-1))=0.998
```

Note, if `YES` is your positive class, the matrix above is assigned to true_positives, ... like this:

```
              --------
              |YES|NO|
|-------------|---|--|
|predicted_YES|TP |FP|
|-------------|---|--|
|predicted_NO |FN |TN|
----------------------
```

While if you define `NO` to be the positive class, the true_positives, ... are assigned like this:

```
              --------
              |YES|NO|
|-------------|---|--|
|predicted_YES|TN |FN|
|-------------|---|--|
|predicted_NO |FP |TP|
----------------------
```